# FedEx : Shipment request failed due to label creation error

Tags: web-services, fedex

I'm trying to create a shipping using FedEx webservice and return commercial invoice. I'm using the request values provided below:

```
Array
(
    [WebAuthenticationDetail] => Array
        (
            [UserCredential] => Array
                (
                    [Key] => XXXXXXX
                    [Password] => XXXXXX
                )

        )

    [ClientDetail] => Array
        (
            [AccountNumber] => XXXX
            [MeterNumber] => XXXXX
        )

    [Version] => Array
        (
            [ServiceId] => ship
            [Major] => 13
            [Intermediate] => 0
            [Minor] => 0
        )

    [RequestedShipment] => Array
        (
            [DropoffType] => REGULAR_PICKUP
            [ShipTimestamp] => 2013-09-23T20:50:27+02:00
            [ServiceType] => FIRST_OVERNIGHT
            [PackagingType] => FEDEX_BOX
            [Shipper] => Array
                (
                    [Contact] => Array
                        (
                            [PersonName] => User
                            [CompanyName] => Company
                            [PhoneNumber] => 56757567456
                        )

                    [Address] => Array
                        (
                            [StreetLines] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 4400 test street
                                    [1] => apt 65, nro 6098
                                )

                            [City] => New York
                            [StateOrProvinceCode] => NY
                            [PostalCode] => 10018
                            [CountryCode] => US
                        )

                )

            [Recipient] => Array
                (
                    [Contact] => Array
                        (
                            [PersonName] => Test
                            [CompanyName] => Test
                            [PhoneNumber] => 4563456
                        )

                    [Address] => Array
                        (
                            [StreetLines] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Test
                                    [1] => 
                                )

                            [City] => New York
                            [StateOrProvinceCode] => NY
                            [PostalCode] => 10019
                            [CountryCode] => US
                        )

                )

            [ShippingChargesPayment] => Array
                (
                    [PaymentType] => SENDER
                    [Payor] => Array
                        (
                            [ResponsibleParty] => Array
                                (
                                    [AccountNumber] => XXXXXX
                                    [Contact] => 
                                    [Address] => Array
                                        (
                                            [CountryCode] => US
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [CustomsClearanceDetail] => Array
                (
                    [DutiesPayment] => Array
                        (
                            [PaymentType] => SENDER
                            [Payor] => Array
                                (
                                    [ResponsibleParty] => Array
                                        (
                                            [AccountNumber] => XXXX
                                            [Contact] => 
                                            [Address] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [CountryCode] => US
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [CustomsValue] => Array
                        (
                            [Currency] => USD
                            [Amount] => 44
                        )

                    [Commodities] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [NumberOfPieces] => 1
                                    [Description] => XXXX
                                    [CountryOfManufacture] => US
                                    [Weight] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Value] => 1
                                            [Units] => LB
                                        )

                                    [Quantity] => 3
                                    [QuantityUnits] => PCS
                                    [UnitPrice] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Currency] => USD
                                            [Amount] => 1
                                        )

                                    [CustomsValue] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Currency] => USD
                                            [Amount] => 3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [RateRequestTypes] => LIST
            [PackageCount] => 1
            [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [SequenceNumber] => 1
                            [GroupPackageCount] => 1
                            [Weight] => Array
                                (
                                    [Value] => 1
                                    [Units] => LB
                                )

                            [Dimensions] => Array
                                (
                                    [Length] => 2
                                    [Width] => 3
                                    [Height] => 4
                                    [Units] => IN
                                )

                        )

                )

            [LabelSpecification] => Array
                (
                    [LabelFormatType] => COMMON2D
                    [ImageType] => PDF
                    [LabelStockType] => PAPER_7X4.75
                )

            [ShippingDocumentSpecification] => Array
                (
                    [ShippingDocumentTypes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => COMMERCIAL_INVOICE
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

If i don't include the ShippingDocumentSpecification part it works perfectly. But when i add it i always get this response no matter what:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [HighestSeverity] => FAILURE
    [Notifications] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Severity] => FAILURE
            [Source] => ship
            [Code] => 6050
            [Message] => Shipment request failed due to label creation error
            [LocalizedMessage] => Shipment request failed due to label creation error
            [MessageParameters] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => CAUSE
                    [Value] => General error from JCLS
                )

        )

    [Version] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ServiceId] => ship
            [Major] => 13
            [Intermediate] => 0
            [Minor] => 0
        )

)
```

Why is this happening? where is there error on the request, cause response is not helping to identify it. Also I'm using a fedex test account, do this have anything to do with this error?...

Thanks.

Comment: SOAP is used by FedEx web-service... i have provided a request and response, i think it should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your request is incomplete:

```
        [ShippingDocumentSpecification] => Array
            (
                [ShippingDocumentTypes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => COMMERCIAL_INVOICE
                    )

                [CommercialInvoiceDetail] => Array
                    (
                        [Format] => Array
                            (
                                [StockType] => PAPER_LETTER
                                [ImageType] => PDF
                                [ImageTypeSpecified] => 1
                                [StockTypeSpecified] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )
```